# SQL finding the total weight

Tags: sql-server

[tables diagram](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wCsKJ.png)

Code used:

```
SELECT
    ROUND(SUM(COALESCE(p.[Weight], 0)), 2) AS [Total weight]
FROM
    SalesLT.SalesOrderHeader soh
JOIN 
    SalesLT.SalesOrderDetail sod ON sod.SalesOrderID = soh.SalesOrderID
JOIN 
    SalesLT.Product p ON p.ProductID = sod.ProductID
WHERE
    DATEPART(YEAR, soh.DueDate) = '2017' 
    AND DATEPART(MONTH, soh.DueDate) = '05' 
     OR (DATEPART(MONTH, soh.DueDate) = '06' 
     OR DATEPART(MONTH, soh.DueDate) = '12') 
    AND soh.ShipMethod = 'Unknown';
```

I got this question wrong and was wondering if someone could see what was wrong with the code? Looks right to me.

Question:

> What's the total weight in kilograms of orders due in May 2017, or June 2017, or December 2017? Only include orders which used an Unknown shipping method. Get the total weight, rounded and padded to 2dp.

Comment: Please provide some sample data, expected results and tag the database you use.

Comment: AND goes before OR. You need brackets. (Or use `IN (...)`.)

Comment: where is quantity in the formula?  if I ship 100 items each 1Kg that is 100Kg  plus the problem with `OR`s in your where clause - it is picking up any rows of months 7 or 11 ignoring the year

Comment: The `DATEPART` functions return values of type `INT` - so in order to avoid unnecessary, costly implicit conversions, when comparing , **do NOT** put the comparison values in single quotes! Use `DATEPART(YEAR, soh.DueDate) = 2017` - on single quotes, makes comparison an **Integer** comparison

Comment: oh sorry I did add the brackets between more OR's. Are you saying because " AND soh.ShipMethod = 'Unknown';" is after my OR it is wrong?

Comment: where has the question gone? don't destroy the question

Comment: I'll rolled your last edit back. Please don't remove substantially change the meaning of a question once asked.

Answer (score 0):

You need both unit weight multiplied by the quantity of those units. If one ships a single item - or - 100 of those items the total weight is not the same.

Plus, you need to couple the year restriction with each of the month restrictions so you get 2017-04, 2017-07, 2017-11. In you original you get 2017-04 but any rows in months 7 and 11. Use parentheses to control the meaning of the predicates.

```
SELECT
  ROUND(SUM(COALESCE(p.[Weight] * sod.OrderQty, 0)), 2) AS [Total weight]
FROM SalesLT.SalesOrderHeader soh
JOIN SalesLT.SalesOrderDetail sod
  ON sod.SalesOrderID = soh.SalesOrderID
JOIN SalesLT.Product p
  ON p.ProductID = sod.ProductID
WHERE soh.ShipMethod = 'UnKnown'
AND DATEPART(YEAR, soh.DueDate) = 2017
AND (
       DATEPART(MONTH, soh.DueDate) = 04
    OR DATEPART(MONTH, soh.DueDate) = 07
    OR DATEPART(MONTH, soh.DueDate) = 11
    )
```

as mentioned by marc_s also avoid the type conversion as `datepart()` returns integers.

Personally I would prefer to use 3 full date ranges instead of using datepart

```
WHERE soh.ShipMethod = 'UnKnown'
AND (soh.DueDate >= '20170401' and soh.DueDate < '20170501')
AND (soh.DueDate >= '20170701' and soh.DueDate < '20170801')
AND (soh.DueDate >= '20171101' and soh.DueDate < '20171201')
```